# Both modal popups appear on click of either button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Im working in twitter-bootstrap3.On click of button "mybtn", the modal with id="myModal" should pop and on click of button "mybtn2", the modal with id="myModal2" should pop. But when I click on any of the two buttons , bot of them popup.What should I do?

Sign In/Up

```
<button id="mybtn2"  style="display:none;" 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-modal-sm">
      Sign In/Up
  </button>

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="myModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" >
//code
</div></div>

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="myModal2"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" >
//code
</div></div>
```

Comment: show your javasript please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the ID of the modal you want to target. Right now, your `data-target` attributes are pointing to the class of `bs-modal-sm` which applies to BOTH of your modals. Try `data-target="#myModal"` or `data-target="#myModal2"` as appropriate.

Here's a bootply demo: [link](http://www.bootply.com/pN4UvjlhLc)