# Different Modal Content for different Images

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

i am a beginner at JS or HTML and i need help with setting different modal content for different images. For example , when i clicked image1, modal will popup showing price, then when i clicked image2, modal will popup showing quantity. Is that possible?

HTML:

```
<div id="portfoliolist">
                <div class="portfolio logo1 mix_all" data-cat="logo" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
                    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">     
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-md" href="#" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
                         <img src="images/p1.jpg" /><div class="b-wrapper"><h2 class="b-animate b-from-left    b-delay03 "><img src="images/link-ico.png" alt=""/></h2>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="portfolio app mix_all" data-cat="app" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
                    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">     
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-md" href="#" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
                         <img src="images/p2.jpg" /><div class="b-wrapper"><h2 class="b-animate b-from-left    b-delay03 "><img src="images/link-ico.png" alt=""/></h2>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>  <!----start-model-box---->
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-md" id="type1" href="#"> </a>
                    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-md light-box" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                        <div class="modal-content light-box-info">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><img src="images/close.png" title="close" /></button>
                         <h3>Prices</h3>
                         <p>Prices</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This solved my questions :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045454/both-modal-popups-appear-on-click-of-either-button?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Specify `data-target` attribute.

See [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes).

Comment: i tried specifying the data-target attribute but i dont seem to get the result also, in fact i tried adding another data modal and when i click the image, the 1st modal will appear followed by the 2nd one...

Comment: I think the question shld had been rephrased, i meant, how can i show different static information on the modals for different images when clicked?

Comment: Just paste the code in the link and edit it as you like. It would work fine.